# Preparing query string from java bean

Tags: java

I am curious to know is there any better way to prepare the query string without checking null values from the Java Bean.

I have below java bean with properties

```
    public class Employee{

    private String name;

    private String address;

    //setters and getters i am not mention here

    }
```

suppose take name as value and address dont have value means null.I want to prepare query string like below:

```
    update table test where name='value from property' where xxx=?
```

Regards,

chakri

Comment: I recommend that you use an ORM such as Hibernate, so that you don't have to do this yourself.

Comment: That's correct Marcelo.But we already have component that will execute only 2 queries.So idont require all hibernate stuff here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the builder pattern to construct the SQL. there's no magic: you have to write each builder class to construct insert, update, select, etc. however, at the end you have a nice encapsulation of the logic. here's how you'd use it,

```
String sql = new EmployeeUpdateBuilder()
    .whereName("Jeff")
    .valueAddress("123 Main Street")
    .build();
```

the code to implement is straightforward, a bit of busy work actually, but the result is nice. if you were going to author a bunch of these for different object types, you could factor a lot out into base classes for each of the various SQL command types (insert, select, etc).

another option would be to generalize the builder. you'd end up with usage like this,

```
String sql = new UpdateBuilder()
    .table("employees")
    .where("name", "Jeff")
    .value("address", "123 Main Street")
    .build();
```

Comment: Jeffery,every property i have to do null and empty string check.i want to avoid that.whatever the properties having without null or empty .i ahve to construct query string.

Comment: so, build the check into your query builder. there's no magic, something has to do the check.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to fire query dynamically. You can check for the null value first and according to that value you can choose the query to fire on db.

Comment: sorry,dont understand what do you mean.

Comment: i want to prepare query dynamically based on property name and it's value.

Comment: My interpretatino of Vimal Bera's answer is that if you use the quotes to place the value to be compared to xxx in a string, you would at worst send to your database the empty string, instead of invalid SQL.

Comment: @user2680017 I updated my answer as per your requirement. Ask me if you need more clarification.

Comment: thanks,that is the first thing anyone can do.how hibernate is doing similar thing?